# How to send array of parameters on nusoap_client in PHP

Tags: php, soap, nusoap

I have this code in general SOAP of PHP:

```
$options = array(
    'login' => 'user',
    'password' => 'pass'
);
$client = new SoapClient($url, $options);
```

I just want to know how can I sending $options in NuSOAP.

```
$client = new nusoap_client($url, 'wsdl');
```

Answer (score 0):

Parameters can be sent along in the call method, as the second parameter like so:

`$soapclient->call( string methodname [ ,array parameters] );`

[Download the documentation](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/files/nusoap-docs/) for more information.

Comment: I'm looking for what I said at the first post. I want to send params on connection in NuSOAP.

Comment: No connection should be made on instantiation. You instantiate the object, manipulate it, and then you use the call method (or your method).

Comment: it's because there is no user or pass set on web service for API functions. as the sample they give me in doc, i've to login first. i just don't know how to do it in NuSOAP. I should try setCredentials to see what happens

Answer (score 0):

NuSoap has a `setCredentials` method to send login and password:

```
$client->setCredentials("user","password");
```

---

```
void setCredentials (string $username, string $password, [string $authtype = 'basic'], [array $certRequest = array()])
```

---

```
string $username    
string $password    
string $authtype: (basic|digest|certificate|ntlm)   
array $certRequest: (keys must be cainfofile (optional), sslcertfile, sslkeyfile, passphrase, verifypeer (optional), verifyhost (optional): see corresponding options in cURL docs)
```

Comment: thanks, just one thing. it seems we only set the values here. in my sample code of SOAP, it sends an associated array with specific keys. If I use setCredentials without keys, does it work fine? ( I found that sample code from Documentation of a web service but I'm using NuSOAP because of server does not support SOAP itself )